# Create a Bitcoin Core wallet from a recovery phrase

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip32-hd-wallets, mnemonic-seed

Is there a way to create a wallet from a Hierarchical Deterministic recovery phrase in Bitcoin Core 0.21.0?

I'm using the x64 Windows cli version, in case that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, bitcoin-core does not support bip39 mnemonic phrases.

Comment: There's no work-around? Convert the mnemonic phrase to a private key and use that to import in Bitcoin Core?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you must use a wallet-client that supports your Seed Recovery data, which may include a passphrase as well as the mnemonic.

Electrum's can be different from the standard BIP39 version.

Once you have restored access to that account-wallet in that client, you then can get the addresses used and their corresponding privkeys.

However if you want to generate new address/keys in Core, the derivation path issues mean you are better off just creating a new account-wallet for Core to use, and transfer the existing coins over if you want just one wallet.